# Running a Series of Commands as Another User or in a Chroot Environment Doesn't Work Unless Contents of Script are Copied and Pasted into a Terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, input

Cutting and pasting parts 1 and 2 of the following script into a terminal works perfectly, but running this file as a script does not because some commands need to be executed as another user (through "su - user") or in a chroot environment. For instance, in part 1, the script has to be executed by the user "lfs".

I've already tried passing commands to other users' shells through "su user -c 'really long list of commands'" and through Here-Documents but none of them seem to work.

The goal is for this to be a script that you can run normally without having to go out of your way to open it up and copy and paste its contents inside a virtual terminal for it to work.

```
##########################################################################
#               PART 1: Run multiple commands as user "lfs"              #
##########################################################################

sudo useradd lfs
sudo passwd -fd lfs
su - lfs    #creates a login shell than brings you to /home/lfs/ as "lfs"

#create a test file
cat > test-file.txt << "EOF"
This is a test file.
EOF

#if everything is fine, it should have been built in /home/lfs/
cat > did-it-work.sh << "EOF"
if [ ! -f /home/lfs/test-file.txt ]; then echo "ERROR: Build error. Exiting."; fi
if [ -f /home/lfs/test-file.txt ]; then echo "SUCCESS: It worked." > it-worked.txt; fi
cat it-worked.txt
EOF
bash did-it-work.sh

#exiting from "lfs" shell
logout #it should be a login shell that you're exiting from; if you get
       #errors, know that there shouldn't be any

#cleanup
sudo userdel lfs && sudo rm -rf /home/lfs/

##########################################################################
#         PART 2: Run multiple commands in a chroot environment          #
##########################################################################

#set up chroot environment
mkdir -p testdir/lib/ testdir/lib64/ testdir/bin/ testdir/usr/bin/
sudo cp /bin/bash testdir/bin/bash && sudo cp /usr/bin/cat testdir/usr/bin/cat
for i in $( ldd /bin/bash | grep -v dynamic | cut -d " " -f 3 | sed 's/://' | sort | uniq )
do
  sudo cp --parents $i testdir
done
for i in $( ldd /usr/bin/cat | grep -v dynamic | cut -d " " -f 3 | sed 's/://' | sort | uniq )
do
  sudo cp --parents $i testdir
done
if [ -f /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ]; then
   sudo cp --parents /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 testdir
fi
if [ -f  /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ]; then
   cp --parents /lib/ld-linux.so.2 testdir
fi

#enter the chroot environment
sudo chroot testdir

#put a script in the chroot environment and run it to see if it works
cat > am-i-root.sh << "EOF"
if [[ $EUID > 0 ]]; then echo "ERROR: Not root user. Exiting."; fi
if [[ $EUID = 0 ]]; then echo "SUCCESS: You are root." > i-am-root.txt; fi
cat i-am-root.txt
EOF
bash am-i-root.sh

#exit the chroot environment
exit

#cleanup
sudo rm -rf testdir
```

If you're wondering what the purpose of this is, it's a simplified version of the problem I face with an automated build system I'm setting up for my own Linux distro. (Instead of making you download and compile packages to test it, this test runs simpler arbitrary commands.) It's been gnawing away at me for days. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution, and it was that with "su user -c ", the executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option cannot be used to execute interractive programs which need a controlling TTY. The bash profile sourced from the script that I ran on my actual build system had a parameter that required interactive mode, which would have required an available TTY. Removing the "-i" (interactive) parameter from that profile solved the problem.

The reason that this worked when copy-pasted was that copying and pasting the commands sent line-by-line input into an interactive virtual terminal. Running it non-interactively as a script interpreted the sequence of commands differently.